# How to cite/reference a paper in latex

Tags: citing, wlscirep

I am preparing a manuscript in Latex. I want to cite/reference a paper in a paragraph.

I cite it using the example format

"This is my manuscript \cite{bibtex_key}."

then it returns me an output as

"This is my manuscript.[1]"

whereas I need it to be like

"This is my manuscript[1]."

Below is the working example, you can compile and see that the reference 1 comes after the full stop which should not be as I cited it before the full stop.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

The introduction goes here \cite{Thomas_book}.

\begin{thebibliography}{unsrt}

\bibitem{Thomas_book}
Thomas, L. \& Ari, R. d. \emph{Biological Feedback} (CRC Press, USA, 1990).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The link for the class file is :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6sl35ul05ryng8/wlscirep.cls?dl=0

Comment: Please prepare a minimal working example (MWE) with the packages you use to reproduce the error. The switching of the citation and the full stop looks very suspicious to me, it is not normal LaTeX behaviour.

Comment: @jknappen I have edited the question and added the working example. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Do you have a link for downloading the `wlscirep` class? Everything works as expected using the `article` class.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes I did link the above mentioned class file.

Comment: It actually compile and successfully generate pdf but the reference comes after full stop.

Comment: Where is the link? There is none in your question, please add it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u6sl35ul05ryng8/wlscirep.cls?dl=0

Comment: @Alenanno I added the link for cls file in my question as well as in the last comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the `wlscirep` class, but inserting a `\relax` after the `\cite` macro seems to move the punctuation to the desired place.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
  The introduction goes here \cite{Thomas_book}\relax.
\begin{thebibliography}{unsrt}
  \bibitem{Thomas_book}
    Thomas, L. \& Ari, R. d. \emph{Biological Feedback} (CRC Press, USA, 1990).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: full stop after citation mark]

Comment: It works for me as I desired. Thanks @XZS. You are really a life saver.

Comment: I further explored and got a better result than given by you. If you use **\!** instead of **\relax**, you will get the full stop very close to reference 1, unlike the above case, where it is at some distance from reference 1. Ultimately, I got the exact output what I was searching at start. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Seeing that the citation is in an exponent (and not in square brackets) the switching of the the dot and the citation looks much more natural (and is in fact recommended by some style guides). When you are required to follow a certain style, do so, even when you disagree with their choice.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I change the document class but I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

The introduction goes here \cite{Thomas_book}.

\begin{thebibliography}{unsrt}

\bibitem{Thomas_book}
Thomas, L. \& Ari, R. d. \emph{Biological Feedback} (CRC Press, USA, 1990).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry dear, I have to move with the same document class. I can't change the class. I, myself, earlier tested for other document class, and it works, but cause problem for this particular class. Anybody other can help me in this regard, it will be highly appreciated. Thanks.